# How to return a value into an asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, restsharp

When I call this method, nothing happens and the application crashes. I think it's due the `ExecuteAsync` method.can someone help me?.This is my code.

**CODE1**:

```
public Task<Connection> Connect(string userId, string password)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("user", userId,
                     "password", password)
            };
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();
        var request = new RestRequest(AppResources.Authenticating);
        client.ExecuteAsync<Connection>(request, response => tcs.SetResult(new 
               JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Connection>(response)));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

I tried this code also but still the same problem exists.

**CODE2**:

```
public async Task<Connection> Connect(string userId, string password)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("user", userId,
                      "password", password)
            };
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();
        var request = new RestRequest(AppResources.Authenticating);
        client.ExecuteAsync<Connection>(request, response => tcs.SetResult(new 
                JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Connection>(response)));
        Debug.WriteLine(tcs.Task.Result.Data);
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean 'crashes'? can you give an error message? a stack trace?

Comment: Nothing append and the application freezes and don't respond

Comment: on which line does it freeze? have you verified that the call is received by your service?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm a beginner

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you want to help yourself to get better answers you could make your question look better.
Click the edit button below your question and spend five minutes reading the "How to Format" section and click the "formatting help »" links too.
Then you will see that when writing your code in markdown you should indent your code by 4 spaces.  If you make your question as appealing as possible you
will be more likely to get the answers you need faster and more up-votes too.

Comment: You could also add in some line breaks to make it all fit on the page at once.

Comment: To be honest, if you're a beginner, asynchronous programming is not something you should do. There's so much that can go wrong, even if you're a very experienced programmer, so I would tip you to either asking someone else to help you with that part (and not just the debugging, but actually writing the code), or to write synchronous code to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` in asynchronous code. Those members are only used when you use `Task` as part of the Task Parallel Library (writing parallel code). They should almost never be used in asynchronous code.

In your case, I suspect that you're calling `Result` on the `Task` returned by `Connect` (or possibly further up the call stack). This can [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

I disagree with @LasseVKarlsen regarding asynchronous code for beginners. I think it is absolutely something you should learn now that the new `async`/`await` language features are out.

I recommend you start with [my introduction](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and follow up with the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and the [TAP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). Then review my [best practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) to avoid the most common pitfalls.